# Preorder tree traversal function which returns an array of integers in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I try to write a function which return an array of integers containing the node values of the binary tree in preorder that is a node value must appear before the values of its left and right child.

- if root is NULL, return NULL
- for every node left child comes before right child

For example;

```
int *a = preorder(bt1);
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
>2_1_3_
```

Here is my work, but it doesn't work, where could be the problem in my code?

```
int* preorder(TreeNode *root) {
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int)*50);
    int i=0;

    if(root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else {
        if(root != NULL) {
            a[i] = root->val;
            i++;
            preorder(root->left);
            preorder(root->right);
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The allocation doesn't make sense. What exactly is unclear?

Comment: Each call of `preorder` is storing the result into a *different* array. That is clearly not what you want. You need to pass the array to each `preorder` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues in the code:

1. You have to allocate the array for results once. Before calling `preorder`
2. You have to keep `i` outside of `preorder` to allow it to change between calls

One example is the following code:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int)*50);
int inx = 0;
preorder(bt1, a, &inx);



void preorder(TreeNode *root, int* a, int* inx) {
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        if(root != NULL) {
            a[*inx] = root->val;
            *inx = *inx + 1;
            preorder(root->left, a, inx);
            preorder(root->right, a, inx);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int& inx` This does not belong to C , C++ allows this .

Comment: The answer needs to be C not C++. And doesn't passing the same `inx` to the two recursive `preorder` calls result in both of them storing into the same index? Also, what is the point of the return value in the solution shown?

Comment: @kaylum `preorder` changes `inx` if it stores anything in the array. And you are correct, it should be a `void` function

Answer (score 0):

In each recursive call of this function you will allocate:

`int *a = malloc(sizeof(int)*50);`

You need to allocate space for array once and then use that same array. Same thing is for using i = 0. You need to use one counter.

You may want create array in `main` function, and then pass array as function argument. Or you could use global array, and access it that way. Same thing for counter variable.

**Note:** I don't see point of memory allocation in your example. You should better use static array if you're sure that tree won't have more then `ARRAY SIZE` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

With the wanted function signature of `preorder()` a solution is not possible. Therefore you need a helper function for the `root == NULL` case and a traversal function which a pointer to the current position in the array. It also returns a pointer to the next free slot in the array. A solution could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    struct TreeNode* left, * right;
};

int tree_size(/*struct TreeNode* tree*/) { return 7; }

int* preorder_(struct TreeNode* tn, int* v) {
    *v++ = tn->val;
    if (tn->left) v = preorder_(tn->left, v);
    if (tn->right) v = preorder_(tn->right, v);

    return v;
}

int* preorder(struct TreeNode* tn) {
    if (tn) {
        int* v = malloc(tree_size(/*tn*/) * sizeof(int));
        preorder_(tn, v);
        return v;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    //    4
    //  2   5
    // 1 3 6 7
    struct TreeNode
        left = {2, &{1}, &{3]}, 
        right = {5, &{6}, &{7}}, 
        root = {4, &left, &right};
    int *v, i;

    v = preorder(&root);
    for (i = 0; i < tree_size(/*tn*/); i++) {
        printf("%d ", v[i]); // 4 2 1 3 5 6 7
    }
    free(v);

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/LCV8uc)